# Why am I getting undefined type error after a forward-declaration?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using this code in C++ CLI. However this shouldn't make any difference from C++.
I'm looking for a solution to get rid of that error.

Code :

```
ref class B;
ref class A;

public ref class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    B^ b;
    void HelloFromA(){
        b->HelloFromB();
    }
};

public ref class B
{
public :
    A^ a;
    B() {}
    void HelloFromB(){
        a->HelloFromA();
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move the bodies of the functions that invoke member functions on the forward-declared classes outside of the headers, to places where definitions are available:

```
void A::HelloFromA(){
    b->HelloFromB();
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler knows that `B` is available, but it does not know that `B` has the `HelloFromB` member function that takes no arguments.

Comment: Thanks now works. However do you know any solution that does that for me ? Because there is already 7000 lines of code which has definition inside the header..

Comment: @Mahdi Visual Assist X provides the [move implementation to source file](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/moveImplementation.asp) refactoring capability.

Comment: @Mahdi - Have you tried to run the example as well, to see the infinite recursion?  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah I made it like that to prevent getting answers like move class B on top of class A :)